# PHP header Syntax

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a registration and login system and I'm getting a syntax error in this code where I'm using

```
header('Location: Profile.php');
```

In the context this code is used as follows:

```
/* send email to new Customer */
$emess = "You have sucessfully registered. ";
$emess .= "Your new username and password are:  ";
$emess .= "\n\n\t$loginName\n\t";
$emess .= "$password\n\n";
$emess .= "We appreciate your interest. \n\n";
$emess .= "If you have any questions or problems, ";
$emess .= " email service@ourstore.com";
$subj = "Your new customer registration"
# $mailsend=mail("$email","$subj","$emess");
header('Location: Profile.php');
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I am learning PHP.

Comment: **What** syntax error? We can't help us if you won't tell us what's wrong.

Comment: It won't throw a syntax error, but the Location header tables an absolute URI, not a relative one.

Comment: that is true that the standard requires absolute url, but most modern browsers can also handle relative urls so this is not the issue.
the issue is of course the missing semicolon

Comment: tip: put an exit(); after your location headers too. Also can someone confirm if the space after the : should now be removed?

Comment: The space after the colon in Location is allowed; it does not need to be removed.

Answer (score 10):

You are missing a semicolon:

```
$subj = "Your new customer registration";
```

Comment: Thanks so much, seem so stupid now.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can happen to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned above, you are missing a semicolon

when you have an internal server error you can look for the error in the log file,

or enabling errors printing on screen (DONT enable it on production) with

```
 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```